# The remote server returned an error: (405) Method Not Allowed. .NET core REST Service

Tags: rest, asp.net-core, http-headers

I have referenced quite a few SO posts *viz.* [The remote server returned an error: (405) Method Not Allowed. WCF REST Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10134632/the-remote-server-returned-an-error-405-method-not-allowed-wcf-rest-service) amongst others however none of them seem to have the same issue that I am experiencing.

Context:
I need to pass in a username and password to a Rest Api and subsequently get returned an authentication token.

Below is my code to do this. I get thrown an Http status code 405 Method Not Allowed exception on the last line:

```
            var uri = "https:/localhost:5001/api/v5/GetToken";
            WebRequest req = WebRequest.Create(uri);
            req.Method = "GET";         
            req.Headers["Authorization"] = "Basic " + Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.Default.GetBytes("user@gmail.com:userPassword1234"));
            HttpWebResponse resp = req.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
```

I then figured that I might be using the wrong method to which I changed it from GET to a POST and that results in a 400 Bad Request error. The 400 Bad Request error makes sense because I am not trying to add data nor create a resource. I am simply doing a retrieve so a GET should be sufficient for this call.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: In the past, I've encountered 405 errors a couple of times. Most of the time it turned out to be related to Mime types of the request or the response, i.e., the server requiring JSON but the client not sending it.

Comment: @citronas Is this in relation to Content-Type?

Comment: @Harold_Finch Yes, are you sending the request with the proper content type?

Comment: Please add code of REST API endpoint you are sending request to